# PHP Email: No data being displayed although email is sent

Tags: php, html-email, contact-form

I'm using g-Recaptcha v3 to pass a hidden token and HTML "Contact" form data to `form.php` file on the localhost, which verifies the g-Recaptcha data, returns a default prompt to end-user and sends an email, via the localhost to the default email address.

The email received does not display data captured, via the HTML "Contact" form. I have tried changing the syntax, I have tried additional "If/Else" statements as well as adding "POST" commands without any success.

HTML contact form section:

```
<!-- The Contact Section -->
            <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-center w3-blue-gray w3-padding-64" style="max-width:1400px" id="contact">
            
                <div class=" w3-container w3-content w3-center" style="max-width:1000px">
                
                    <h2 class="w3-wide">Contact</h2>        
                    
                    <p class="w3-opacity"><i>~ Lets Talk About Your Current Needs ~</i></p>
                    
                    <form id="comment_form" action="form.php " method="post"  target="_blank" >                     
                        
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-text-gray w3-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name: ex. Mark (with no spaces, punctuations or symbols)" name="fname"  maxlength="32" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,32}" required><br>
                        
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-text-gray w3-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name: ex. Wilson (with no spaces, punctuations or symbols)" name="lname"  maxlength="32" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,32}" required>
                        
                        <input class="w3-input w3-section w3-border w3-text-gray w3-center" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email: ex. yourname@domainname.com" name="email" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" required>
                        
                        <input class="w3-input w3-section w3-border w3-text-gray w3-center" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number: ex.(112)112-1112 or 1121121112" name="phone" pattern="^(\s*)?(\+)?([- _():=+]?\d[- _():=+]?){10,14}(\s*)?$" required>
                        
                        <textarea class="w3-input w3-section w3-border w3-text-gray w3-center" placeholder="Please Place Your Comment Here"  name="comment"  rows="5" required></textarea>

                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="w3-text-black"><br><br>

                    </form>
                                        
                    <script>
                    // when form is submit
                        $('#comment_form').submit(function() {
                            // we stopped it
                            event.preventDefault();                         
                            var fname = $('#fname').val();
                            var lname = $('#lname').val();
                            var email = $('#email').val();
                            var phone = $('#phone').val();
                            var comment = $("#comment").val();
                            // needs for recaptacha ready
                            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                                // do request for recaptcha token
                                // response is promise with passed token
                                grecaptcha.execute('----------My Public Key----------', {action: 'create_comment'}).then(function(token) {
                                    // add token to form
                                    $('#comment_form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');
                                        $.post("form.php",{fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, phone: phone, comment: comment, token: token}, function(result) {
                                                console.log(result);
                                                if(result.success) {
                                                        alert('Thanks for posting your comment!')
                                                } else {
                                                        alert('Spammed Message - This Process Will Be Terminated')
                                                }
                                        });
                                });;
                            });
                      });
                    </script>
```

### **form.php**

```
<?php

        $fname;$lname;$email;$phone;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
          $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        }if(isset($_POST['lname'])){
          $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        }if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
          $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $comment=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['token'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['token'];
          }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "--------------My Secret Key-----------------";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        // POST REQUEST TO SERVER

        $url =  'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        if($responseKeys["success"]) {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true'));
        } else {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => 'false'));
        }
        
        // COLLECT CONTACT FORM DATA        
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];       
        $number = $_POST['phone'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        // FORMAT EMAIL 
        $to = "default@emailaddress.com";
        $headers = "From: {$to} \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$email } \r\n";
        $subject = "New form submission ... \r\n";
        $body = "First Name: {$fname} \r\n";
        $body .= "Last Name: {$lname} \r\n";
        $body .= "Email: {$email} \r\n";
        $body .= "Phone: {$phone } \r\n";
        $body .= "Comment: {$comment}";
        
        // SEND EMAIL to DEFAULT RECIPIENT VIA LOCALHOST

        $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

HTML contact form:

[image: HTML CONTACT FORM]

Google g-recaptcha v3 verification prompt:

[image: Google g-recaptcha v3 verification prompt]

Email, via contact form, with missing data:

[image: Email, via contact form, with missing data]

Comment: `$('#fname')` implies there is an element with an _id_ named _fname_. Try adding an _id_ attribute to each form element. `<input ... id="fname" ...>`

Comment: Thank you!  Your suggestion of adding the "id" attribute to the input section of my HTML contact form worked.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer). Alternatively, you can ask waterloomatt to provide an answer and then accept it.